# Change highlighted navbar buttons on page scroll (not working)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, navbar

I am trying to achieve a change in the navbar when the user scrolls through a one page site, as each section reflects a different navbar button, i would like them become highlighted as the user scrolls to the corresponding page,

I have looked at and tried to implement a few of the solutions out there, (heaps on here) but i am not having any luck.

my code for js is here:

```
    // Cache selectors
var lastId,
    topMenu = $("#primary-menu"),
    topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+30,
    // All list items
    menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
    // Anchors corresponding to menu items
    scrollItems = 300 + menuItems.map(function(){
      var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
      if (item.length) { return item; }
    }) ;


// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(function(){
   // Get container scroll position
   var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;

   // Get id of current scroll item
   var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
     if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
       return this;
   });
   // Get the id of the current element
   cur = cur[cur.length-1];
   var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

   if (lastId !== id) {
       lastId = id;
       // Set/remove active class
       menuItems
         .parent().removeClass("active")
         .end().filter("[href=#"+id+"]").parent().addClass("active");
   }                   
});
```

Code from header.php - declares navbar

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar">
            <nav id="site-navigation" class="navigation main-navigation" role="navigation">
                <button class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'twentythirteen' ); ?></button>
                <a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'twentythirteen' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentythirteen' ); ?></a>
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu', 'menu_id' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
            </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
        </div><!-- #navbar -->
```

Code from page-home.php - example of a section:

```
    <div class="section6" id="connect">
<div class = "heading1">connect</div>
<div class="contactform">
<?php if( function_exists( 'ninja_forms_display_form' ) ){ ninja_forms_display_form( 6 ); } ?>
</div>
</div>
```

And relevant css code:

```
.main-navigation {
text-align:right;
clear: both;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 1080px;
min-height: 75px;
position: relative;
  background-image:url("images/logo-white.png");
background-size:70px auto;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:10px 15px;
}

ul.nav-menu,
div.nav-menu > ul {
line-height: 75px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0 40px 0 0;
}

.nav-menu li {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;

}

.nav-menu li a {
color: #737373;
display: block;
font-size: 10px;
line-height: 1;
padding: 15px 20px;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform:uppercase;
letter-spacing:3px;
outline:none;

}


.nav-menu li.active,
.nav-menu li.active > a {
color: #FCFBD9;

}

.navmenu li a .active {
color: #FCFBD9;
}

.nav-menu li:hover > a,
.nav-menu li a:hover,
.nav-menu li:focus > a,
.nav-menu li a:focus {
color: #FCFBD9;
}
```

This script is from a friend's site, which works perfectly. I can't see why it won't do anything to mine as our naming conventions are identical..

Perhaps it could be a css issue?

the site is www.enitrecreative.com/stone

Thanks for any help/suggestions/advice!

Comment: can you show us the HTML for the nav bar?

Comment: You'll need to provide more context. It could be either a HTML or CSS issue. There are a lot of class and id specific calls in that javascript and if your styles or HTML don't match up ... the above code won't do what you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Easy what you need to do is use a scrollspy so in the nav where you specify your a href you would use say #about then you just name your section about like so  and it should work.